# NSUserDefaults for high score is not working on iOS 8 Simulator?

Tags: swift, ios8, integer, nsuserdefaults

I've tried to synchronize the saved data but my game still does not store the highest score. I can't find whats wrong with the replacing of the highScore with score if it is higher. Sorry I'm a beginner who just started learning iOS programming.

```
init(size: CGSize, score: NSInteger) {

    super.init(size: size)
    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

    //To save highest score
    var highscore = 0
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if (score > highscore){
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(score, forKey: "highscore")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
    var savedScore: Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("highscore") as! Int


    //To get the saved score
    var savedScore: Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("highscore") as! Int
```

Comment: In your edited code `if (score > highscore)` will *always be true* if `score > 0` because you just set `highscore` to `0` two lines up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's step through your code.

First, you overwrite whatever the high score was with 0:

```
//To save highest score
let highscore = 0
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(highscore, forKey: "highscore")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Then, you're checking if "highscore" is in the defaults:

```
if let highscore: AnyObject = userDefaults.valueForKey("highscore") {
```

A few notes:

- This will *always be true* because you *just set it*
- You should be using `objectForKey(_:)`, not `valueForKey(_:)`
- But really you should be using `integerForKey(_:)` not `objectForKey(_:)`, since `highscore` is always an `Int`.
- You can delete `: AnyObject` because `objectForKey(_:)` returns `AnyObject?`

Then, we go into the code:

```
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(score, forKey: "highscore")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

You are now overwriting the `0` score you just added earlier with whatever `score` is.

Finally, your `else` block, which will never get called, sets `highscore`, even though you just did that before the `if` condition.

```
}
else {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(highscore, forKey: "highscore")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

It's not clear from your code what you want to do, but you did say this in your question:

> I can't find whats wrong with the replacing of the highScore with score if it is higher.

Well, for one thing, you're never checking which one is higher.

I think you might be trying to do this:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let highscore = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")

if score > highscore {
    defaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore")
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```